# Fortran READ(*,*), WRITE(*,*) arguments

Tags: fortran

This question has been covered somewhat in previous SO questions. However, previous discussions seem somewhat incomplete.

Fortran has several I/O statements. There is `READ(*,*)` and `WRITE(*,*)`, etc. The first asterisk (*) is the standard asterisk designating an input or output from the keyboard to/from the screen. My question is about the second asterisk:

The second asterisk designates the format of the I/O elements, the data TYPE which is being used. If this asterisk is left unchanged, the fortran complier uses the default format (whatever that may be, based on the compiler). Users must use a number of format descriptors to designate the data type, precision, and so forth.

(1) Are these format descriptors universal for all Fortran compilers and for all versions of Fortran?

(2) Where can I find the standard list of these format descriptors? For example, `F8.3` means that the number should be printed using fixed point notation with field width 8 and 3 decimal places.

EDIT: A reference for edit descriptors can be found here: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Edit+descriptors

Comment: You say the question is about the second asterisk (denoting list-directed IO), but apart from the question implied by "whatever that is" you ask only about edit descriptors in an explicit format.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @francescalus What I mean by "whatever that is" is that different Fortran compilers will execute different things. gfortran might execute at one precision, the intel fortran ifort might choose another. Other SO posts discuss this in detail. 
My main question is to learn how to use the second asterisk correctly.

Comment: The meaning of the second asterisk is clearly but loosely defined (varying by compiler as you say).  However, I think one of is confused: using this second asterisk is wholly at odds with using edit descriptors such as `F8.3`.  Do you mean, then, how to use an explicit format instead of the asterisk?

Comment: @francescalus Yes, I may be confused then. The question should be this: how should I use the second asterisk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, as a clarification, the 1st asterisk in the READ/WRITE statement has a slightly different meaning than you state. For write, it means write to the default file unit (in linux world generally standard out), for read it means read from the default file unit (in linux world generally standard in), either of which may not necessarily be connected to a terminal screen or a keyboard.

The 2nd asterisk means use list directed IO. For read statements this is generally useful because you don't need a specified format for your input. It breaks up the line into fields separated by space or comma (maybe a couple others that aren't commonly used), and reads each field in turn into the variable associated with that field in the argument list, ignoring unread fields, and continuing onto the next line if not enough fields were read in (unless a line termination character `\` is explicitly included).

For writes, it means the compiler is allowed to determine what format to write the variables out (I believe with no separator). I believe it is allowed to do this at run time, so that you are all but guaranteed that the value it is trying to write will fit into the format specifier used, so you can be assured that you won't get `*******` written out. The down side is you have to manually include a separator character in your argument list, or all your numbers will run together.

In general, using list directed read is more of a convenience to the user, so they don't have to fit their inputs into rigidly defined fields, and list directed writes are a convenience to the programmer, in case they're not sure what the output will look like.

Comment: Do you happen to know *the* standard reference for WRITE(*,*) edit descriptors using Fortran90? Fortran95?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Do you mean, if you `write(*,*) ...` what user-specified format `write(*,fmt) ...` would have the equivalent result?  If so, my answer completely misunderstood that.

Comment: Technically _THE_ reference would be the ISO standard, but you probably don't need to go that far. I have found the descriptors on [this](http://www.pa.msu.edu/~duxbury/courses/phy480/fortran90_refcard.pdf) cheat sheet to be more than adequate.

Comment: As an aside, a reasonable technique is to _bootstrap_ your format specifier. Example: `write(fmt, *) "A, I", num, ", 3f", num2, ".3"` and then `write(*, fmt) "string", intgr, real1, real2, real3` so you can determine how much space you need at run time, but still get some control over the format.

Comment: @BradRichardson The cheat sheet is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you have a data transfer statement like `read(*,*) ...` it's helpful to understand exactly what this means.  `read(*,*)` is equivalent to the more verbose `read(unit=*, fmt=*)`.  This second asterisk, as you have it, makes this read statement (or corresponding write statement) list-directed.

List-directed input/output, as described elsewhere, is a convenience for the programmer.  The Fortran standards specify lots of constraints that the compiler must follow, but this language has things like "reasonable values", so allowing output to vary by compiler, settings, and so on.

Again, as described elsewhere, fine user control over the output (or input) comes with giving a format specification.  Instead of `read(*,fmt=*)`, something like `read(*,fmt=1014)` or `read(*,fmt=format_variable_or_literal)`.  I take it your question is: what is this format specification?

I won't go into details of all of the possible edit descriptors, but I will say in response to (2): you can find the list of those edit descriptors in the Fortran standard (Clause 10 of Fortran 2008 goes into all the detail) or a good reference book.

To answer (1): no, edit descriptors are not universal.  Even across Fortran standards.  Of note are:

- The introduction of `I0` (and other minimal-width specifiers) for output in Fortran 95;
- The removal of the `H` edit descriptor in Fortran 95;
- The introduction of the `DT` edit descriptor in Fortran 2003.

Comment: And why is that in some cases format specifies _must start_ with a `1X`

Comment: You mean the now-deleted carriage control?  Another notable change, indeed.  Let's see if I can say something sensible.